# Is the image of a Lie-subalgebra under the exponential map a subgroup?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. If $\mathfrak{h}$ is a Lie-subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$, then the image of $\mathfrak{h}$ under the exponential map is supposed to be a subgroup of $G$.

My question is how to prove this, preferably using the definition of the exponential map via the flow of left-invariant vector fields, or the first one from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory)#Definitions) and without using the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true in general. The image of $\mathfrak h$ *generates* a subgroup of $G$, but the image might not be the whole subgroup. For example, if $\mathfrak g$ is the set of all $2\times 2$ real matrices, and $\mathfrak h$ is the subalgebra of trace-free matrices, then the smallest subgroup of $\text{GL}(2,\mathbb R)$ containing $\exp(\mathfrak h)$ is $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$; but the following matrix is in $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ but not in the image of the exponential map:
$$
A=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-\frac12 & 0 \\
0 & -2
\end{matrix}
\right).
$$
To see why, note that if $A = e^B$ for some $B\in \mathfrak h$, then $C = e^{B/2}$ would be a real matrix whose square is $A$. But a straightforward computation shows that there is no such matrix.

Comment: saying that the image generates a subgroup is basically no statement at all right? (since every subset generates a subgroup...)

Comment: @0x539: Yes, I guess you're right. What's more interesting is that the image generates a subgroup _whose Lie algebra is $\mathfrak h$_ (using the fact that the Lie algebra of a subgroup of $G$ can be canonically identified with a subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$).